# Apply firewall rules to an HTTP load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'd like to take advantage of the Google Cloud Platform HTTP(s) load balancer, but I need to restrict access to the load balancer to a specific block of IP's. Is it possible to apply firewall rules to a GCP HTTP(s) load balancer?

Answer (score 7):

At the moment it is not possible to set firewall rules over the GCE Load Balancers. Nevertheless there is a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=425&q=load%20balancer&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Resource%20Service%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Log) in place. Since the original source IP is re-written by the LB, you can use the [X-Forwarded-For header](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#components) to obtain the original client and filter it accordingly on your servers.

Answer (score 7):

As Carlos stated in his answer here you cannot apply firewall rules on Google's HTTP Load Balancer.
But you could set some allow/disallow rules on IP ranges through Google's Cloud Armor Security Policies ([Use case](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-concepts#use_case_1_limiting_access_to_the_gcp_https_load_balancer) / [How to](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies)) by setting the target on the backend service of an HTTP load balancer.

Comment: Cloud Armor is the firewall for Google Cloud's HTTP(S) load-balancer, as [stated by Google employee in this Google issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904903#comment120).

Answer (score 0):

you can use cloud armor and create a rule in cloud armor to block or allow ip address.

you can find more details https://cloud.google.com/armor

Answer (score -1):

I think that today vpc firewall works.